# How to convert JPEG to DICOM image in Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, dicom

I really need your help. I need to find out how to convert a JPEG image to DICOM in Matlab? Does somebody know how can I do that?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Image Processing Toolbox has a function called `dicomwrite`.

```
I = imread(inputJpgFilename);
dicomwrite(I, outputDicomFilename);
```