# Using dicomwrite with color images

Tags: matlab, dicom

I am trying to write a sequence of color images to a dicom file in Matlab. Each image is of type `uint16`. The sequence is stored in a 4D matrix named `output` of size 200x360x3x360 (num of rows x num of cols x num of channels x num of images). When I execute `dicomwrite(output,'outputfile.dcm')`, it gives the following error:

[image]

It says data bit depth is 8 but I've ensured that each image is 16-bit. Not sure what's going wrong.

The [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/dicomwrite.html) for `dicomwrite` says it can write color images as well. In fact `dicomread` can read color dicom images such that the size of the matrix which stores the read data is 200x360x3x360. So I guess it should be possible to write color images as well using `dicomwrite`. Any help in this regard is appreciated. There is a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8111010/5022962) but it doesn't talk about color image sequence.

Comment: It means 8 bit data is expected and you provide 16 bit.
The Dicom Images on Secondary capture image class (1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.7.4) expected to contain only 8 bit pixel data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comment by JohnnyQ is correct.
[From this page](https://www.dabsoft.ch/dicom/3/A.8/) down in section A.8.5.4, they list the Multi-frame True Color SC Image IOD Content Constraints (partial list quote):

> In the Image Pixel Module, the following constraints apply:
>
> - Samples per Pixel (0028,0002) shall be 3
> - Bits Allocated (0028,0100) shall be 8
> - Bits Stored (0028,0101) shall be 8
> - High Bit (0028,0102) shall be 7
> - Pixel Representation (0028,0103) shall be 0

It seems matlab will not do the conversion for you, so you should down convert each 16-bit color channel to 8-bit for DICOM

Comment: Thanks @rkh and @Johnny. Yeah conversion to 8-bit worked. But, I still have a doubt. When I read a dicom file and extracted one of the slices, the slice was `int16`. Then why is 8-bit depth required for writing?

Comment: @Ruchir, it is certainly possible to have a DICOM file that violates the standard.  It could very well be that your source image is a 16-bit multi-frame true color.  Or, perhaps, it is a mutliframe grey scale 16-bit to comply with the standard, but it really a color image...

Comment: The source should be a multiframe grayscale 16-bit image. So, when I read it, every slice of it is a 16 bit grayscale image.